# Android L Battery Saver Mode - startActivityforResult

Tags: android, android-intent, start-activity, powermanager, battery-saver

As you all might be aware the Android L has introduced a new feature called battery saver mode. I want direct the user from my app to that specific activity in the Settings page. How should I go about doing that?

E.g.: For starting a "Data Usage Activity" in settings page, I do this

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.Settings$DataUsageSummaryActivity"));
startActivityForResult(i, 0);
```

How can I do something similar for going to the Battery saver page?
Settings -> Battery -> (Options on top right) -> Battery Saver

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Intent battSaverIntent = new Intent();
battSaverIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.Settings$BatterySaverSettingsActivity"));
startActivityForResult(battSaverIntent, 0);
```

That worked for me.

But be aware that this hardcoded string is not from [Android Settings](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html), so this shortcut might change, I suppose.

**EDIT:**

Now the ACTION has been made visible in the Android Settings (since API level 22).
See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_BATTERY_SAVER_SETTINGS).

The action is now called **ACTION_BATTERY_SAVER_SETTINGS**

But beware that not all phones have this setting, so you need to guardcheck.

Comment: Awesome Thanks. Follow up question - Do you think we can change it programmatically ? Any other better practices to do the above?

Comment: I think you have to use this way for now.
But it seems that soon there will be a way to use a predefined action for that (see [android source code , line 880](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/provider/Settings.java)) called ACTION_BATTERY_SAVER_SETTINGS